# ARM vector instructions - 16-byte vs 8-byte

Tags: assembly, vector, arm, inline-assembly

I am familiar with SSE instructions but trying to get to grips with the basics of ARM assembly (coded via C intrinsics). I am confused by how to use the vabal_u8 and vabal_high_u8 instructions, and specifically the fact that they take parameters of a different type (one takes uint8x8 and one takes uint8x16).

I believe that if I have two variables of type uint8x16 then I can compute the absolute difference of the 'high' half of these vectors using vabal_high_u8, but how to I compute the absolute difference of the 'low' half? I cannot just call vabal_u8 because that expects an input type of uint8x8, not 8x16.

It seems to me that what I should be looking for is a method to extract the low half of a uint8x16 and represent it in a uint8x8 (and I suspect that is really just a cast that would not require any underlying instructions). However, if so, I can't work out how to do that. Can anybody help set me right?

*Note 1: What I am trying to do overall is to implement a sum-of-absolute-differences calculation on a long string of bytes, and vabal seems to be the best way to achieve that without overflowing the uint8 type.*

*Note 2: Perhaps I would be better off just loading uint8x8 and using vabal_u8 rather than trying to work with uint8x8 inputs, but it seems as if there should be a way to do 8x16 like I am trying to...?*

*Note 3: this would be so much simpler in SSE, thanks to the _mm_sad_epu8 intrinsic!*

**Update:**

I had tried to describe what I “really” wanted to do, but if I boil it down to my fundamental question about the vector instruction set:

The descriptions for `vabal_high_u8(uint16x8_t a, uint8x16_t b, uint8x16_t c)` and for `vabal_u8 (uint16x8_t a, uint8x8_t b, uint8x8_t c)` are identical, and read (bold is my emphasis):

*Unsigned Absolute difference and Accumulate Long. This instruction subtracts the vector elements in the **lower or upper** half of the second source SIMD&FP register from the corresponding vector elements of the first source SIMD&FP register, and…*

This implies to me that they are a pair of instructions, one of which can be used to operate on the lower half of a 16-bit vector and the other of which can be used to operate on the upper half of a 16-bit vector, and certainly if you can do the upper then it surely makes sense to have a way to do the lower as well. However, the two available intrinsics have different types for their input parameters. Suppose I already have uint8x16_t b and c. I can operate on the upper half using vabal_high_u8. How do I perform the equivalent operation on the lower half? I cannot use the partner instruction vabal_u8 because that accepts a type uint8x8_t instead of uint8x16_t. There is no vabal_**low**_u8(uint16x8_t a, **uint8x16_t** b, **uint8x16_t** c)...

Comment: You likely want to perform `vabal_u8` in your loop and add the partial accumulated values at the end.

Comment: OK, so I can certainly make that work in this specific case (my Note 2), but I feel there is still a more general issue I am not understanding. If the xxx_high_yyy intrinsics exist, surely there must be a straightforward way of achieving what I'd describe as "xxx_low_yyy", operating on the *same* vector type as with xxx_high_yyy?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want ... do you want to operate on 16 bytes, and get 16 byte result? There is the `vabaq_u8` for that. I don't think you can operate on 16 bytes and get 16 halfword results.

Comment: I've tried to update my original question with an addendum to clarify what I'm getting at...

Comment: Okay I understand now, thanks for the clarification. Sounds like you need `vget_low_u8` which hopefully gets optimized away.

Comment: ARM intrinsics are weirder (and often compile inefficiently) because in 32-bit mode, (not AArch64), one `q` register aliases onto two `d` registers for the high and low halves.  e.g. `q1` is composed of `d3:d2` so where on x86 you'd have to shuffle and add to do the first step of a horizontal sum of an XMM reg, on NEON you can do an 8-byte vertical SIMD op between the two halves.  As I mentioned, current compilers are often bad at this, and make poor asm for ARM intrinsics, vs. usually doing very well for SSE and Altivec.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. vget_low_xxx sounds like exactly what I was looking for - and, as you say, hopefully the compiler would in reality be able to optimize it away due to the weirdness (which I am dimly aware of) mentioned by Peter Cordes.